# Unable to play HLS m3u8 file with AWS CloudFront Signed Cookies

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, video.js, hls.js, vivado-hls

I am working on a project where I will need to play HLS encrypted video (.m3u8) file. I am using CloudFront and signed cookies to secure the content. I am able to play .m3u8 file without signed cookies but when I use signed cookies then cookies do not get send in requests.

I am using the alternate domain for CloudFront distribution and I confirm that apart from .m3u8 file I am able to access all other files using signed cookies.

After research, I found that if I set `withCredentials` to true like the following code then signed cookies will be send in request:

```
player.ready(function() {
    player.src({
        src: 'https://protected.example.com/output-plain/art.m3u8',
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
        withCredentials: true
    });
});
```

This code works and signed cookies are getting send in request however I started getting a new error which is:

*`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://protected.example.com/output-plain/art.m3u8undefined' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`*

Then I found that I have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to true. however, this does not work for me.

I am using video.js library, I have also tried hls.js and getting the same error and stuck at same place.

I am stuck on this issue for the last 7 days and I think AWS docs are really overwhelming, I have referred many questions on SO and issues on Github but still no luck. Hope someone will help me here.

Here is the screenshot of CloudFront distribution behavior:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here is my php and js code; index.php:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://protected.example.com");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body>

<video
        id="video_player"
        class="video-js"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
        data-setup='{}'
        width=600 height=300>
      
    </video>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.js"></script>

<script>
    var player = videojs('video_player')

    player.responsive(true);

    player.ready(function() {
        player.src({
            src: 'https://protected.example.com/output-plain/art.m3u8',
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
            withCredentials: true
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is S3 bucked CORS Policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            ""
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you make it work? I try for 3 days without success.

Comment: @DzungPV Yes it's working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is within the browser's error message, "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'."  Your S3 bucket's CORS policy cannot use a wildcard for the AllowedOrigins value.

Also your empty AllowedHeaders value *may* be removing the Host value from the preflight request check, so let's set it to a wildcard just to be safe.

If you update your S3 bucket's CORS policy to this, it should resolve the issue:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://example.com",
            "https://protected.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Brian. it's working in production. But I cannot access from localhost. I've changed my machine host to dev.example.com and my production url is example.com. basically, whenever I try to access video from dev.example.com (localhsot) it says

```
 'http://dev.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: You need to add dev.example.com to your S3 CORS policy in AllowedOrigins.